# Filter Firebase collections on arrays or objects in Firebase Firestore

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am since a few days looking for a solution for my problem. What i try to do is loading objects from Firestore with a filter lower in the structure.

```
/meetings (collection)
    /meetingId
        /people (object)
            - uid1:1
            - uid2:1
```

Without a where query, it works fine. But since i want to validate on people in the object. I walk against walls.

```
FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    Firestore.instance
        .collection('meetings')
        .where('people.${user.uid}', isEqualTo: '1')
        .orderBy('sessionStart', descending: true)
        .snapshots()
        .listen((data) {print(data);});
```

Returns zero results. Also when i self implement a `array-contains`. It works not. Since i want implement rules on my data structure, i need a filtering.

Every time i execute a query i get a request to create a new index. `com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException: FAILED_PRECONDITION: The query requires an index. You can create it here`.

When i follow the url, i get the suggestion to create the following index:

```
Collection: meetings
Fields: people.QkrzIBRs3TNHcTbYGSHsZjFPvlj2 ASC sessionStart DESC
```

What will result in a index per user, what is not my wish.

Can someone help me with this, guide me to the correct solution? I will be thankful for it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after a lot of trial and error I found the possible solution.

The `sortBy` made it impossible to execute the query. If i remove it and just only use the `where` it works perfect.

This was the solution:

```
FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    Firestore.instance
        .collection('meetings')
        .where('people.${user.uid}', isEqualTo: '1')
        .snapshots()
        .listen((data) {print(data);});
```

The rule i needed to create was:

```
match /meetings/{document=**} {
    allow read, list: if resource.data.people[request.auth.uid];
}
```

At the end i was still missing sort functionality. So i resolved in the code after creating Meeting objects from it:

```
meetings.sort((Meeting from, Meeting to) => from.sessionStart
            .toIso8601String()
            .compareTo(to.sessionStart.toIso8601String()));
```

There are probably better solutions, so if you know a better solution, reply please.

Hope this will help other people